# Modified holomorphic projection

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\Gamma$ be a smooth projective curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $\Gamma$. Denote by $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\ldots,\Gamma_n$ a finite collection of smooth curves intersecting $\Gamma$ transversally. My question is:

**Does there exist a non-constant holomorphic function $\pi: U \setminus \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \Gamma_i \to \Gamma \setminus \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \Gamma_i$** ?

The situation as in the following picture. [image]

I can build a smooth map $\pi$ easily by partition of unity. Intuitively,  $\pi$ seems like the tubular neighborhood projection of $\Gamma$ ? But unfortunately, holomorphic tubular neighborhood does not exist in general. Thank in advanced !

Comment: If $n$ is greater than or equal to the degree of the curve I believe you can achieve that. It resembles me the case where the curve is negatively embedded and has a neighborhood isomorphic to a neighborhood of the zero section of its normal bundle.